# New monitor/tv, overscans(?) in 1920x1080 in Ubuntu

Tags: nvidia, xorg

I have a new TM2792S monitor/tv. It does not look good in 1920x1080, the Unity menu is barely visible and also the top panel. So it looks like it overscans.

My xorg.conf is only configured to use nvidia as driver, nothing else.

This is my Xorg.0.log: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5606146/

There are alot of rows like this:

[ 14466.180] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0): The EDID for LG Electronics TM2792 (DFP-1) contradicts itself:
[ 14466.181] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     mode "1920x1080" is specified in the EDID; however, the
[ 14466.181] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     EDID's valid VertRefresh range (58.000-62.000 Hz) would
[ 14466.181] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     exclude this mode's VertRefresh (50.0 Hz); ignoring
[ 14466.181] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     VertRefresh check for mode "1920x1080".

xrandr gives this output:

$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 598mm x 337mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   60.0     59.9     50.0     30.0     25.0     24.0     30.0     30.0     25.0
   1360x768       60.0
   1280x1024      60.0
   1280x720       60.0     59.9     50.0
   1152x864       60.0
   1024x768       60.0
   800x600        60.3
   720x576        50.0     25.0
   720x480        59.9
   640x480        60.0     59.9     59.9

I found this command to make it look better: nvidia-settings --assign CurrentMetaMode="DFP-1: 1920x1080 { ViewPortOut=1850x1045+40+20, ViewPortIn=1920x1080 }"

But, with this you still see that the resolution is somehow wrong, it's not 1:1 pixel-mapped AFAIK.

Comment: Changed mode on the monitor to "Just scan" instead of "16:9". Now I don't need that ViewPortX-change but it still looks really bad.

Comment: I tried connecting my TV up PC with HDMI it looked terrible!  When I switched to an old RGB cable the quality was way better.  I've never seen a TV look as good as a monitor yet!

Answer (score 1):

Changing the monitor/tv to "Just scan" + installing Ubuntu tweak to enable changing of fonts hinting & antialiasing did some good. Then I also switched picture mode on the monitor/tv to Game instead of Standard. Now even better.

So now it's maybe as good as it will get.